# Object referans not set with ksoap2

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am developing an android app with soap services. But,It does not work when i added request property. Am i missing something?

```
public class WebServiceCallerImp {

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetForexStocksandIndexesInfo";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetForexStocksandIndexesInfo";
private static final String URL = "http://mobileexam.veripark.com/mobileforeks/service.asmx";


public static String GetForex() {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("IsIPAD", "true");
    request.addProperty("DeviceID", "test");
    request.addProperty("DeviceType", "ipad");
    request.addProperty("RequestKey", "%%UmVxdWVzdElzVmFsaWQyNzowNDoyMDE3IDEzOjEy%%");
    request.addProperty("Period", "Month");


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println("output: " + response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("@@@@: " + e.toString());

    }
    return "null";
}
```

**Response**

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Denizbank.IpadApplication.Integration.ForexIntegration.StocksandIndexes.GetForexStocksandIndexesInfo(StocksandIndexesRequest req)
```

at Denizbank.IpadApplication.Service.Service.GetForexStocksandIndexesInfo(StocksandIndexesRequest request)

**Soap Request**

[image]

Where do i make mistakes? please help me.

Comment: I guess problem with <soapenv:Header/> remove that one.Because you do not start that tag and put only finish tag part.

Comment: thanx andy, but not working

Comment: see my answer it works for me.I do this thing and it works for me.

Comment: @CenkGün Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I do the same code and no error in my project.

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = null;
    soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    new MarshalBase64().register(soapEnvelope);
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    SoapPrimitive result = null;

    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(SERVER_URL, Const.HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    aht.debug = Const.LOG;

    try {
        Log.print("SOAP_ACTION::" + SOAP_ACTION, "SERVER_URL::" + SERVER_URL);
        Log.print("Request", "" + aht.requestDump);

        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        Log.print("Response", "" + aht.responseDump);
        result = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        Log.print("-----------Request :: ", "" + aht.requestDump);
        Log.print("=====================FINAL RESPONSE================");
        Log.print("RESPONSE :: " + result);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        if (Const.LOG) Log.print("UnknownHostException", "" + e);
        if (Const.LOG) Log.print("Exception in util", e.getMessage());
        soapEnvelope = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (Const.LOG) Log.print("IOException", "" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        soapEnvelope = null;
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        if (Const.LOG) Log.print("XmlPullParserException", "" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        soapEnvelope = null;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        if (Const.LOG) Log.print("OutOfMemoryError", "" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        soapEnvelope = null;
        result = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (Const.LOG) Log.print("Exception", "" + e);
        Log.print("Utils", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        soapEnvelope = null;
    } finally {
        soapEnvelope = null;
        request = null;
        SOAP_ACTION = null;
        SERVER_URL = null;
        aht = null;
    }
```

Const.LOG value is true.

Comment: I tried the solution. But the response is null. Could you test with my parameters in your solution?

Comment: I tried this answer too, still no correct answer yet.